# DoesNotExist at /cart/ matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want show item in cart.html page in my cart but when i add tshirt item in cart it's gives Error `Product matching query does not exist.` and when i add Product item in cart it gives error `Tshirt matching query does not exist` when I click on Cart

**cartitem.py file:**

```
def cartitem(request):
    cart=request.session.get('cart')
    if cart is None:
        cart=[]
    for c in cart:
        tshirt_id=c.get('tshirt')
        product_id=c.get('product')
        product=Product.objects.filter(id=product_id)
        tshirt=Tshirt.objects.get(id=tshirt_id)
        c['size']= Sizevariant.objects.get(tshirt=tshirt_id, size=c['size'])
        c['tshirt']=tshirt
        c['product']=product
    return render(request,"cart.html",{"cart":cart})
```

Comment: @Finisher- Log the cart object you receive in the view and show us.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :-

There are some antipatterns in your view.

```
def cartitem(request,pk):

    cart=request.session.get('cart')
    if cart is None:
        cart=[]

    for c in cart:
        tshirt_id=c.get('tshirt')
        product_id=c.get('product')
        product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=pk)
        tshirt=Tshirt.objects.get(pk=pk)

        c['size']= Sizevariant.objects.get(tshirt=tshirt_id, size=c['size'])
        c['tshirt']=tshirt
        c['product']=product

    return render(request,"cart.html",{'cart':cart,'product':product,'tshirt':tshirt})
```

Change your urls.py into this :-

```
path('<int:pk>',views.cartitem,name='carttime'),
```